# .NET web.config encryption: "The RSA Key Container could not be opened"

Tags: .net, aspnet-regiis.exe

This relates to interactive use of a .NET app, and encrypting a portion of the app.config.

Command: aspnet_regiis -pdf "testSection" "C:\temp"
Error:

```
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319.0
Administration utility to install and uninstall ASP.NET on the local machine.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Decrypting configuration section...
Failed to decrypt using provider 'TestKeys'. Error message from the provider:
The RSA key container could not be opened. (C:\temp\web.config line 68)

The RSA key container could not be opened.
Failed!
```

I imported the crypto kit from the original system without error:

```
aspnet_regiis -pi "TestKeys" "C:\Testthing.xml"
```

I have tried adding permissions, e.g.

```
aspnet_regiis -pa "TestKeys" "test2\administrator"
aspnet_regiis -pa "TestKeys" "administrators"
aspnet_regiis -pa "TestKeys" "users"
```

Nothing helps.

I am logged in interactively as administrator, and importing the key and testing decryption all logged in interactively as the same user, on Win2012-R2.

I would like to be able to LIST the crypto kits present, but it appears that is not possible?

What is my next step?

(On the original system, I can encrypt and decrypt all day long)